# Initialize an std::array of a class without a copy/move constructor?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, copy-elision, parameter-pack

Let's say I have a class without a default constructor called `A`.

I can create an array of `A` objects (e.g. `l_Array` in the below code) without copy/move constructors, but I have an error when the array is a member of another class (e.g. initializing `b` in the below code).

Is it possible to achieve class initialization?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

class A
{
public:
    explicit A(int x) : m_x {x} {}
    A(const A &) = delete;
    virtual ~A() {}
    A & operator=(const A &) = delete;
private:
    int m_x;
};

template <std::size_t N>
class B
{
public:
    template <typename ... Types,
              typename std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Types) == N, int> = 0>
    constexpr explicit B(Types&& ... s) : m_t_Array {static_cast<A>(s)...}
    {
    }
private:
    std::array<A, N> m_t_Array;
};

int main(int, char**) {
    std::array<A, 2> l_Array { A{1}, A{2} };
    B<2> b {A{1}, A{2}};

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```bash
<source>:21:54: error: static_cast from 'A' to 'A' uses deleted function
    constexpr explicit B(Types&& ... s) : m_t_Array {static_cast<A>(s)...}
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:30:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'B<2>::B<A, A, 0>' requested here
    B<2> b {A{1}, A{2}};
         ^
<source>:8:5: note: candidate constructor has been explicitly deleted
    A(const A &) = delete;
    ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: where is the error, and what is the error message?

Comment: Without copy/move constructor, how do you expect `s` to go from `B(Types&& ... s)` to `m_t_Array {static_cast<A>(s)...}`?

Comment: On the other hand, you can use an aggregate initialization if you remove the constructor and made `m_t_Array` public.

Comment: Not having a default constructor isn't the problem here. The problem is that you have deleted the copy constructor.

Comment: Templates tend to needlessly complicate things. Have you tried defining `B` as a non-template? That is, replace each `N` in the definition of `B` with `2` (since your test case is `B<2>`) and eliminate that template. Then hack away at the constructor template; replace `Types` with the types you expect will be deduced. Do you still get an error you cannot explain?